# VBA huge data summary

Tags: vba, excel

I have been searching and doing this task for like weeks, but never found a solution.
I hope you guys can advise me with a solution.

My condition is as below:
1. I have 2 excel workbooks 
   (1st: Log.xlsx - to summarize data,
    2nd: data.xls - data source)
2. In log.xlsx, I have production date, product id, and lot#
3. In data.xls, I have production yield result (different worksheet for different id)
   FYI, worksheet number is about 100 worksheets
4. I want to search for yield result(data.xls) on same date, product id, and lot#(match with
 from Log.xlsx), then display the yield result in Log.xlsx
5. data.xls worksheet name is different from product id, but actual product id is shown in
 cell B2

Can you advise me on how to make this possible?
Really appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that code is in log.xlsx, and both workbooks are currently open, this will copy columns 4 through 7 from data.xls to log.xlsx

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DataSummary()
Dim wbData As Workbook
Dim wsLog As Worksheet
Dim wsDataSet As Worksheet
Dim i, j, k As Integer
Dim prodDate As Date
Dim prodID As String
Dim lotNumber As Integer

Set wbData = Workbooks("Data.xls")
Set wsLog = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

For i = 2 To wsLog.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    prodDate = wsLog.Cells(i, 1).Value
    prodID = wsLog.Cells(i, 2).Value
    lotNumber = wsLog.Cells(i, 3).Value
    For Each wsDataSet In wbData.Worksheets
        If wsDataSet.Cells(2, 2).Value = prodID Then
            For j = 4 To wsDataSet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                If wsDataSet.Cells(j, 1).Value = prodDate And wsDataSet.Cells(j, 3).Value = lotNumber Then
                    wsLog.Cells(i, 4).Value = wsDataSet.Cells(j, 4).Value
                    wsLog.Cells(i, 5).Value = wsDataSet.Cells(j, 5).Value
                    wsLog.Cells(i, 6).Value = wsDataSet.Cells(j, 6).Value
                    wsLog.Cells(i, 7).Value = wsDataSet.Cells(j, 7).Value
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wsDataSet

Next i

End Sub
```

[Here is link to excel files with code and sample data.](http://speedy.sh/tuJ6D/example.zip)

Below is code with additional check. It puts "0" when theres no matching yeild.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DataSummary()
Dim wbData As Workbook
Dim wsLog As Worksheet
Dim wsDataSet As Worksheet
Dim i, j, k As Integer
Dim prodDate As Date
Dim prodID As String
Dim lotNumber As Integer
Dim foundIt As Boolean
Dim Message As String

Message = "0"
Set wbData = Workbooks("Data.xls")
Set wsLog = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

For i = 2 To wsLog.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    foundIt = False
    prodDate = wsLog.Cells(i, 1).Value
    prodID = wsLog.Cells(i, 2).Value
    lotNumber = wsLog.Cells(i, 3).Value
    For Each wsDataSet In wbData.Worksheets
        If wsDataSet.Cells(2, 2).Value = prodID Then
            For j = 4 To wsDataSet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                If wsDataSet.Cells(j, 1).Value = prodDate And wsDataSet.Cells(j, 3).Value = lotNumber Then
                    wsLog.Cells(i, 4).Value = wsDataSet.Cells(j, 4).Value
                    wsLog.Cells(i, 5).Value = wsDataSet.Cells(j, 5).Value
                    wsLog.Cells(i, 6).Value = wsDataSet.Cells(j, 6).Value
                    wsLog.Cells(i, 7).Value = wsDataSet.Cells(j, 7).Value
                    foundIt = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wsDataSet
    If Not foundIt Then
        wsLog.Cells(i, 4).Value = Message
        wsLog.Cells(i, 5).Value = Message
        wsLog.Cells(i, 6).Value = Message
        wsLog.Cells(i, 7).Value = Message
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Please remember that this is only rough scetch of real solution, you need to add exception handling, more checks to see if data is correct, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much!!Finally I can summarize the data!
As expected from experts. Thank you again!.

Can I ask just one more question?
What should I add to display "0" for lot number without yield/
unidentified lot number?

Thank you in advance!!